# joomla pass variable between views

Tags: php, model-view-controller, joomla, joomla-extensions, joomla-component

I'm in the middle of programming a joomla component, this component will have a multiple step form for registration, the first one containing 2 radio buttons. What is the easiest approach to pass the variable from the radiobutton on to step2? when the user submits the first form the controller is called to display the second step, is there an easier approach to this? Thanks in advance.

Code:

step1 of the form (view code):

```
<form name="step1" action="<?php echo JRoute::_('index.php option=com_mycomponent&task=mycomponent.register'); ?>" method="POST">
<input type="radio" name="placement" value="0" checked /> Option 1<br />
<input type="radio" name="placement" value="1" /> Option 2<br />
<div class="next" onClick="document.forms['step1'].submit();"></div>
</form>
```

Controller code to handle mycomponent.register

```
class mycomponentControllermycomponent extends JController

{

    public function register()

    {
    $this->setRedirect(JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_mycomponent&view=default&layout=step2', false));
    }

}
```

I would like to pass the value from the radio to step2 ;)

Hope i didn't miss a topic concerning this already, couldn't find one atleast!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the register method you can access the radio value and then pass it in the link to your view:

```
    public function register()
    {
        $placementOption = JRequest::getInt('placement', 0, 'post');

    $this->setRedirect(JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_mycomponent&view=default&layout=step2&placement=' . $placementOption, false));
    }
```

In your view of step 2 (view.html.php), you can then access the option in the same way (this time the value is in GET not POST):

```
$placementOption = JRequest::getInt('placement', 0, 'get');

$this->assignRef('placement', $placementOption);
```

Finally, if you want to access it in the views template (e.g. default.php)

```
<?php echo $this->placement; ?>
```

Comment: The first method doesn't seem to be working, it's always returning 0 :/ JRequest::getInt doesn't seem to fetch me the value

Using Joomla 2.5.4 by the way.

Comment: In that case just use `(int)$_POST['placement']` and `(int)$_GET['placement']`.

Comment: Still not working unfortunatly, also tried $placement = JRequest::getVar('placement'); with no success :/

Comment: Figured it out, was a fault in my controller :) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I just resolved an issue like that in Joomla. What I did is simple and works fine.

1) I created an article with a form inside the html editor of the article.

2) in this html code of the article, for the form I gave 
  form method="POST" action="child.php".

3) Now, child.php is a page inside my joomla installation folder that has an html page exactly as my template layout and links and article etc. So, I made child.php a page that looks like as any other page on my website, but also with a form inside it.

4) Inside this child.php there is a form. Then the field I want to populate from the article with the form inside it i gave the 
value="?php echo $_POST['VARIABLE']; ?", where VARIABLE is the name of the field of my
html form article.

So, this is it, now my article html form redirects me to child.php page and child.php is populated with the variable of my previous html article.

Comment: Thank you for coming to Stack Overflow and posting your answer Panagiotis!